# Hibernate, association table with extra columns : null error

Tags: java, hibernate

I've got two tables with a many to many relationship, and an association table linking the two with extra columns.

Following tutorials ([this one in particular](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-many-to-many-example-join-table-extra-column-annotation/)), in order to represent that, I have created two entities corresponding to my normal tables, and another for my association table with an embedded id.

To guarantee unicity, I have overridden methods `equals` and `hashCode` and the collections are of type `Set`.

When i persist i'm only getting a null error (see the whole error below), so this gives me no clue about what i'm doing wrong.

Following are the relations of the entities, how they are set and the error.

Entity 1 `Prestation` :

```
@OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="id.prestation", cascade={CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST})
private Set<Louer> louers = new HashSet<Louer>(0);
```

Entity 2 `Materiel` :

```
@OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="id.materiel")
private Set<Louer> louers = new HashSet<Louer>(0);
```

Entity 3 `Louer` :

```
@AssociationOverrides
(
    {
    @AssociationOverride(name="id.materiel", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "ID_MAT")),
    @AssociationOverride(name="id.prestation", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="ID_PREST"))          
    }
)

@Transient
private Materiel materiel;

@Transient
private Prestation prestation;
```

Embeddable class `LouerPK` :

```
@ManyToOne
private Materiel materiel;

@ManyToOne
private Prestation prestation;
```

Setting :

```
louer.setMateriel(mat); 
louer.setPrestation(prest);
prest.getLouers().add(louer);
```

Error :

```
ERROR [model.exception.DAOException] (default task-50) null
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Add more details about your entities and what you are doing when you got this error. Also most important thing is you have to paste complete stacktrace of the error, the error in your post is not having any details about where the error is and whether it is from hibernate or not.

Comment: First of all thanks for answering. About my entities, i think i have put all the relevant code regarding my issue, if not then what do you need exactly ? For the error I am getting it just after the Setting part of my question when i persist the Prestation entity. And it is actually all the error message that you see here.